# DNS authentication for blocked sites

Tags: networking, dns

We're looking to setup some restrictions employees won't have access to social media sites on workstations. However, some workstations needs to have access. One method I've tried was DNS zone, however, I'm not sure how to authenticate for those who needs to have this access. Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is off-topic here since it it not a programming question, but you should be able to ask it on [sf].

Comment: Oh! okay thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You might want to look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488112/is-it-possible-to-force-setting-cname-record-of-the-dns/35494550#35494550) it explains why this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with DNS, what you are looking for is a proxy server, depending on your environment you can use either Squid Proxy (linux) or Microsoft Internet Security & Acceleration Server (Windows). Each has their own way of restricting access to certain sites based on users and user groups so you would need to review the documentation for the specific site you are after but this should give you a starting point and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Neat, I will have a look. We currently operate off of a local windows server so I'll look into the microsoft option.

Comment: The beauty of the Windows option is that it integrated directly with AD so users with authenticated AD sessions will automatically be authenticated for the proxy server connections and shouldn't need to enter their usernames and password again. In addition it allows you to define the rules based on AD user groups rather than needing to specify each user manually. ISA also offers additional features like remote access to your office network and proxying of office web applications over the net to authenticated users (if enabled, switched off by default)