# How to prevent users from accessing .pdf files untill they are not being redirect from any page of website by using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I prevent users from accessing .pdf file directly from url?

I've a page that contains several `<a>` with .pdf href.
And I want that if someone click on these links then it should be go to the relative path and open the document. but If someone trying to copy and paste link in other tab then document shouldn't be open.

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Allow access to specific referrer url/page only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854117/php-allow-access-to-specific-referrer-url-page-only)

Comment: maybe!
But how can I check this for .pdf file?
That's why I was asking. :(

Comment: Either write a php handler for serving the file (you may want to use PATH_INFO too) or write a rule using mod_rewriter in .htaccess to check if referer  is correct. However, you must be aware that all of those solutions are easy to work around and knowledgeable person may still fetch the file without even going to your download page.

Comment: What you ask only is of limited sense. The server has no concept of a "tab" or something similar. All you _could_ do is evaluate the "referer" http header to find if that request actually originated from a clicked link. Or you could try some ajax magic using a request token. But obviously all headers can be easily spoofed. So the question is: _why_ would you want to prevent such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.
Thanks for your precious time.
Here is my code that I'm using in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov)$ http://example.com/ [NC]
```

Hope now you all understand that what I wanted to do.